# Compile and run a finished project which includes sound files

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, audio, release

Developing with C# on Visual Studio 2012.

Just finished a project which includes sound files that it needs to play on certain moments and when I copy the exe from the release and run it somewhere outside the solution folder it gives me a framework error when the sound file needs to be played.

Comment: try publishing instead of copying, but what is the error.

Comment: [link](http://gyazo.com/a324c2eeb2363952fc4e4c49f389c362) - thats the error

Comment: Exception information usually hold the answer to the problem. Please include the details of the exception that is being thrown.

Comment: A mere image of the same window we all see whenever there's an exception isn't going to help, friend. Show the *actual* exception message, trace, and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are including your sound files in your project, but the sound files are simply sitting in your project directory.  Try [adding them as resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), or set the "Copy Local" property to "copy if newer" in the properties of the sound files in your project.  If you absolutely need a single file that you can give to other people, I suggest looking into adding them as a resource, as that will actually bundle them into the exe.  However, how you access them from within the code will change slightly.

Comment: How can you tell given how little details there is on the actual problem? O.o

Comment: Given that the error he posted is a generic unhandled exception and was unaware of how to easily get the real exception that was being thrown, the language in the question, and the fact that this was something that I too was wondering many years ago when I was getting started, I felt it fitting to mention resources, as it is a common question for beginners delving into deployment for the first time.  What a run-on sentence!

Comment: @selkathguy it's a possibility, yes, but that's still a wild guess as there's no clue whatsoever on what the exception is. For all we know it may not even be related to resources. Could be some faulting event or something.

Comment: True, but simply relocating an exe which is looking for files in the local directory would certainly throw an exception.  You are absolutely correct that it could be any number of things, I just started with the one most definite.

Comment: Yep, you guys are absolutely right.

And it works, thanks alot!

Comment: @Yarzz if I may, I suggest that you give exception details next time. Otherwise it won't always be that easy. :)